# Returning All Results when Field is blank

Tags: php, mysql, search

Hi I have a dropdown which is feeding value into a search form.  There are two criteria for search.  Property Category & Property Subcategory.  The search is working nicely when both are selected.  Property Category has five options : Blank, Residential, Commerical, Industrial, Agricultural.. I want to structure the query so if the value is blank in property category it should show all results matching with Residential, Commercial, Industrial and Agricultural.  Currently leaving it blank gives no answers.

I have tried two ways, using arrays, and then structuring mysql IN array.. but the problem is how to search in an array or in a variable in mysql...

following is the html form

```
<select class="searchpropertyinputs" name="property_category" id="property_category" onchange="subcategory('property_category', 'property_subcategory');">
    <option value="">Property Type</option>
    <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
    <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
    <option value="Industrial">Industrial</option>
    <option value="Agricultural">Agricultural</option>
</select>
</br>

<select class="searchpropertyinputs" name="property_subcategory" id="property_subcategory">
    <option value="">Property Subtype</option>
</select>
</br>
```

php

```
$property_category = ($_GET['property_category']);

$select = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_property WHERE (property_category='$property_category' AND property_subcategory='$property_subcategory') LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
```

I am trying to do the following but the problem is that if value is selected it is a variable otherwise if it is blank then it is an array.. hence structure the query is a problem

```
if ($property_category == ""){
$myarray[1] = "'Residential'";
$myarray[2] = "'Commercial'";
$myarray[3] = "'Industrial'";
$myarray[4] = "'Agricultural'";
$property_category = implode(", ", $myarray);
}

$select = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_property WHERE property_category IN ($property_category) LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$count = $select->rowCount();
```

the desired result is do the search based on user input, but if user does not select anything (blank value) then give all the results that exist in the column.

this is not working, it is giving no results

```
$select = $con->prepare(
"SELECT * FROM tbl_property 
WHERE property_category LIKE
    CASE WHEN '$property_category' = '' 
    THEN '%'
    ELSE '$property_category'
    END CASE
    LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$count = $select->rowCount();
```

Comment: So, essentially, you don't want the `WHERE` clause when both dropdowns aren't selected, right?

Comment: yes i am thinking of putting an if statement inside the query to do the search on the property_category only when there is a value in it

Comment: sounds like a good idea..

Comment: your solution using `IN` could work, but would make it hard to maintain. Think about if you ever added a new category in the interface, you'd have to remember to add it to your `$myarray` or else those results would never be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be working

```
$search = array(
    "select" => "SELECT * FROM tbl_property",
    "where" => "WHERE property_category='$property_category'",
);

if (empty($property_category)) {
    unset($search["where"]);
}

$search = implode(' ', $search);

$select = $con->prepare($search);
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$count = $select->rowCount();
```

this seems to be working also

```
$search =
    "SELECT * FROM tbl_property " .
    (empty($property_category) ? "" : "WHERE property_category='$property_category' ");

$select = $con->prepare($search);
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$count = $select->rowCount();
```

now the problem is that why do i take so long to understand and do things...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$where = array();
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_property";
if (!empty($property_category)) {
    $where[] = "property_category='$property_category'";
}
$search_query = $select_query;
if (!empty($where)) {
    $search_query = $select_query . " Where " . implode(" ", $where);
} 

$result = $con->prepare($search_query);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result->execute();
$count = $select->rowCount();
```